# How to sort a list by datetime in python?

Tags: python, sorting, python-datetime

I am writing a .py file to sort lists by time which contain the following information

> date, time, emp_id, action_performed

There is a question asked about this on stackoverflow but I couldn't exactly follow(I am new to python)

I also checked out the sort function and the datetime library but couldnt get it to work.

```py
list = 
[
('2017/09/10 13:19:38', 'employee_id', 'enrolled'),
('2017/09/10 12:15:21', 'employee_id', 'deleted'),
('2017/09/10 21:19:34', 'employee_id', 'enrolled'),
('2017/09/10 22:42:50', 'employee_id', 'deleted'),
('2017/09/10 16:53:03', 'employee_id', 'enrolled')
]
```

I just want to know which action was performed first.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: In your case, with this date format (implying `yyyy/mm/dd`) as simple `list.sort()` would do the task.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: _I also checked out the sort function and the datetime library but couldnt get it to work_ Show us what you tried.  If you just _tell_ us you tried something, without showing the actual code, we can't point out what you did wrong.

Comment: For your sake don't override the builtin `list`. When you do that you can't use the `list` function anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run 'print list.sort()', it returns me 'None', am I doing it right?

Comment: `list.sort()` will sort the list and return `None`. `sorted(list)` will leave the list as it is but return a new sorted list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
list = 
[
('2017/09/10 13:19:38', 'employee_id', 'enrolled'),
('2017/09/10 12:15:21', 'employee_id', 'deleted'),
('2017/09/10 21:19:34', 'employee_id', 'enrolled'),
('2017/09/10 22:42:50', 'employee_id', 'deleted'),
('2017/09/10 16:53:03', 'employee_id', 'enrolled')
]
sorted_list = sorted(list, key=lambda t: datetime.strptime(t[0], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Use the `key` parameter of the `sorted` function, in this case it tells the function to parse the first element of each tuple as a datetime string with the format `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'` and use that value for sorting.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sorted_list = sorted( list )
```

=)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a simple list.sort() which sorts the list in place, or sorted(list) which returns a sorted copy of the list would work perfectly — as long as the dates and times follow Y/M/D H/M/S.

To get the first performed action in one line, you could use:

```py
first_action = sorted(list)[0]
```